# How do I break this infinite loop

Tags: python

Im trying to create a menu. The idea is to make the script loop back to the main menu when the number two is selected. It loops back but when i select number 1 it just keeps looping. How do i fix this.

```
import os
import sys

def mainmenu():
    print """

this is a test menu

"""
mainmenu()

choice = raw_input("DMF>>")
if choice == '1':
   def men1():
       print """

 this is the second menu

 """

 men1()

 def back():
     men1_actions['mainmenu']()

 men1_actions = {
      'mainmenu': mainmenu,
      '2': back,
      }

 while True:
       choice2 = raw_input("DMF>>")
       if choice2 == '2':
          back()
```

Comment: remove `while True:` to stop looping. Simple!

Comment: it breaks the loop but exits the script. Im trying to make it go back to the main menu so i can select option 1 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure with what you are pertaining to exactly but you can first define the functions and then just call on one raw_input to indicate whether the input is 1 or 2.

```
def mainmenu():
    print """this is a test menu"""
def men1():
    print """this is the second menu"""
while True:
    choice = raw_input("DMF>>")
    if choice == '1':
        mainmenu()
    elif choice == '2':
        men1()
    else:
        print """Please choose between 1 or 2"""
```